# Is there any way to makethis below code faster in Eigen squaredNorm

Tags: c++, eigen3, tbb

I have below Eigen C++ code and doing squredNorm calculations 10milliyon times.

Is there anyway to make it more robust/faster .

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <tbb/parallel_for.h>
#include "tbb/tbb.h"
#include <mutex>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(){ 

int numberOFdata = 10000008;
Eigen::MatrixXf feat = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(numberOFdata,512);
Eigen::MatrixXf b_cmp= Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(1,512);
int count_feature = feat.rows();
std::vector<int> found_number ;
std::mutex mutex1;

for (int loop = 0 ; loop<16 ; loop++){

double start_1 = static_cast<double>(cv::getTickCount());                                                                  
tbb::affinity_partitioner ap;
tbb::parallel_for( tbb::blocked_range<int>(0,count_feature),
                       [&](tbb::blocked_range<int> r  ) 
    {
        for (int i=r.begin(); i<r.end(); ++i)
        {

        auto distance = ( feat.row(i)- b_cmp ).squaredNorm();                                   
        if (distance < 0.5) {                                                                   
                mutex1.lock();            
                found_number.push_back(i);
                mutex1.unlock();
                            
                           }
        }
    },ap);

double timefin = ((double)cv::getTickCount() - start_1) / cv::getTickFrequency();
std::cout  << count_feature   << " TOTAL : "  << timefin << std::endl;

}
}
```

Compile flags :

```
-Xpreprocessor   -std=c++11  -fopenmp -pthread -O3  -mavx2 -march=native -funroll-loops -fpermissive
```

eigen version 3.3.7
tbb opencv and eigen linked.

You can remove opencv and use a different elapsed time calculation.

Thanks

Comment: What I found disabling Eigen vectorization and NDEBUG make the speed almost same with numba. changed all column based matricex also calc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be faster by a factor of about 4 if you store `feat` in the same order in which you access it (i.e., `Eigen::RowMajor` in your case).

Minimal example removing all non-Eigen related things:

```
  int numberOFdata = 10000008;
  Eigen::Matrix<float,Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> feat = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(numberOFdata, 512);
  Eigen::RowVectorXf b_cmp = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(1, 512);
  int count_feature = feat.rows();
  std::vector<int> found_number;

  for (int loop = 0; loop < 16; loop++) {
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < feat.rows(); ++i) {
        float distance = (feat.row(i) - b_cmp).squaredNorm();
        if (distance < 0.5f) {
          found_number.push_back(i);
        }
      }
    };

    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end-start;
    std::cout  << count_feature   << " TOTAL : "  <<
     diff.count() << std::endl;
  }
```

Godbolt-Demo (reduced dimension of `feat` due to memory-limitations): https://godbolt.org/z/b6r5K4Yxv

Comment: to change all row it decreased  1.2 sec to 0,69 sec.
to change all column its almost 0,64 sec